# Options for manual camera controls on a phone app

Tags: controls, touch-screen, sliders, smartphone, camera

I am making an advanced camera app for Android. Right now, I have come up with 2 ideas for implementing 3 manual controls (focus distance, sensor sensitivity, and exposure time) on a touch screen:

- Put one slider on the bottom edge of the display (would become the right edge on landscape), and put 3 buttons underneath it to change which setting the slider would change. The advantages of this method include eliminating the chance of accidentally moving another slider (more on that in the 2nd idea), and covering a smaller area of the viewport (it extends to the area behind this slider when the capture aspect ratio is wide).
- Put 3 sliders next to each other for each one of the settings. The advantages of this are being able to change different settings faster, but it allows changing the wrong setting accidentally as described before, and will cover up more area on the viewport.

Which one of those is better? Maybe there is a better implementation that I have not thought of.

**EDIT:**
I did not mention that in both implementations, all values are visible at all times. They will be shown under their respective buttons or sliders.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently been trying out Google's Snapseed and I have to say that their UI for this is really intuitive.

[image: Screenshot of Google Snapseed filter UI]

When you swipe up or down, the menu above fades in and changes which item is currently selected. Swiping left and right changes the value of that item. This is great as you don't have to be precisely adjusting a slider with your finger and can quickly adjust values with a high level of control.

Comment: This is a nice option. Although this way you wouldn't be able to see all of the current settings. I forgot to mention that in my first method, the value of each settings is shown under its button, and in the second one the values would be shown under the sliders. My bad.

Comment: Do you really need to see all of the values on screen? That just sounds like added clutter. All you have to do to see them in this case is swipe up or down or you could even show them on a tap. If you absolutely do need all values on screen then just copy the same UI that's in every Pro tab of any modern phones camera app.